# I'm looking for photo sets from drone photography to convert to 3D models. Where can I find them?

Tags: photography, online-resources

I'm looking for photo-sets taken by drones as part of a science assignment to generate 3D Models. Where in the net can I find some sites which can share some samples?

Comment: Wecome to Drones.SE - however, I suspect you may have more success asking about this on [Photography.SE](https://photo.stackexchange.com/), as I would guess the main issues here are image licencing and photography resources?

Comment: Thank you for the info.

Comment: I have some raw sets i can get you if this is for education.   I’m interested in your application.  What are you trying to achieve?  You can take your own using an app like litchi.  Or get into DroneDeploy.  @Kralc , i think this is on topic. Photography would likely not have photos specific to aerial drone mapping.

Answer (score 2):

Search youtube for videos with the keywords FPV and ORBIT.  This is the motion that will give you 360 degree frames of an object.  Also search for Point of Interest mode for DJI drones.  Then you can use a youtube downloader service to download the video and then extract the frames you are interested in. Here is an example of a dji poi video https://youtu.be/hlfOVBAmc4o?t=48

If you put -tutorial in your search terms it will weed out all the tutorial videos that you don't want
https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=dji+point+of+interest+examples+-tutorial

Answer (score 1):

[Open drone map on GitHub](https://github.com/OpenDroneMap) has high quality data sets taken from drones for 3d models

Comment: Welcome to the site! Please add some content to your answer describing the Open Drone Map tool and how it can be used to solve the question/problem. So-called "link-only answers" aren't very useful in most cases.